# Float loses precision in javascript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, precision, web3js, floating

I have an amount of tokens I want to burn in a web3 project. this amount is `0.29806008728157019` I want to pass this amount to `web3.utils.toBN(Math.trunc(amount * 1000000000000000000));` as it is without changing it . the problem that I can't pass it as String and when I parse it using `ParsFloat` it becomes `0.2980600872815702` and this is a problem because I want exactly the same float.

I tried to use `toFixed(17)` and `toPrecision(17)` but they change the float to string and the same problem occurs.

So how I can pass it as a float without changing it?

Comment: What you want is simply not possible. The value `0.29806008728157019` cannot be accurately represented using the number type in JavaScript.

Comment: Also, `29806008728157019` exceeds the [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER), so even the resulting value of your calculation cannot be represented accurately using the number type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . So i there any other solution to do that ?

Comment: You can't use the number type, so you'd have to fall back to some library that can handle large numbers. What is the type of `amount`? If it is already a number, then the precision has already been lost. If it is a string, you can most likely use the BN.js library which you are already using in `web3.utils.toBN()`. I can't really test it locally, but I'd assume it would be something like `web3.utils.toBN(amound).mul(web3.utils.toBN('1000000000000000000'))`. The result of this expression is already a BN instance, so you don't need to use `web3.utils.toBN()` on the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BigNumber library requires integers. Therefore, you need to use a [BigDecimal library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-big-decimal) to perform the multiplication.

Then you would do:

```js
let bn = web3.utils.toBN((new bigDecimal("0.29806008728157019"))
  .multiply(new bigDecimal("1000000000000000000"))
  .floor().getValue());
```